# What does unique factorization exactly mean here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Given $a$ and $b$ are integers:

$$ 3^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^a = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 5^b $$

The answer is as follows:

> Since both sides of this equation are integers and have, up to order, unique factorization, it follows that $a = 1$ and $b = 2$ is the only solution.

What does unique factorization exactly mean here? I looked up the phrase unique factorization on google but I do not really understand it. Can you explain it at the pre-calculus level? Also, what aspect of 'integers' makes the solution $a = 1$, and $b = 2$?

Comment: Search Fundamental Arithmetic Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every positive integer is either prime or composite or the number one.

If the number is composite then it can be factored as a product of smaller numbers.  Ex:  $120 = 12\cdot10$ or we could say $120 = 30\cdot4$ or we could say $120 = 6\cdot10\cdot2$.

If we factor a number into smaller composites and then factored those number we'd eventually factor it do to a factorization containing only primes.  Ex:  $120 = 12\cdot10 = (3\cdot4)\cdot(2\cdot5) = 3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot5$  or we could say $120 = 30\cdot4 =(6\cdot5)\cdot(2\cdot2) = 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot2\cdot2$ or $120=6\cdot10\cdot2 = 2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot5\cdot2$.

And if we have multiple occurrences of the same prime factor we can list them as a power.  Ex: $120 = 3\cdot2^3\cdot5$ or $120 = 2^3\cdot3\cdot5$ or $120 =3\cdot5\cdot2^3$.

Now perhaps the most anti-climatic conclusion you'll ever see.

No matter how you break a number down into primes you will always and up with the same primes and the same number of each of them.  Each number has only one unique way of being broken down into primes.

And that is what unique prime factorization means.

So if you have $3^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^a = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 5^b$ then you have a number.  By the Left-Hand side we know it factors into: two $3$s, one $2$, two $5$s, and some $7$ but we don't know how many.  On the RHS we see that it factors down into: one $2$, two $3$s, one $7$, and some $5$s but we don't know how many.

But by the Unique prime factorizations we know the two lists of components must be exactly the same.  So how many $7$s are there?  Well, by the RHS we know there is one $7$. And how many $5$s are there?  Well, by the LHS we know there are two $5$s.

So that's that.  If $3^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^a = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 5^b$ then $a =1$ and $b = 2$ and then number is $3^2 \cdot2\cdot5^2\cdot7 = 9\cdot2\cdot5^2\cdot7 = 3150$.

---

Note: The really hard way to do it:

$3^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^a = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 5^b$  Divide both sides by $3^2\cdot2$

$5^2\cdot7^a = 7\cdot5^b$.  Divide both sides by $7$.

$5^2\cdot7^{a-1} = 5^b$.  Divide both sides by $5^2$.

$7^{a-1} = 5^{b-2}$.

So.... the question is: what (integer) power can you raise $5$ to get a (integer) power of $7$ (or vice versa).  The answer is: $5$ and $7$ are prime; there isn't any such power. The only way this makes sense is if  $7^0  = 5^0 = 1$.  So $a-1 = b-2 =0$.

The point being: if you have ever told that  $3^a\cdot5^b = 3^c\cdot5^d$ and you are told $a$ and $b$ are  integers, then it should be immediately clear $a = c$ and $b = d$.

Comment: hey @fleablood , can you explain more about why the power has to be zero..? Because now I've encountered a similar question where the answer is like yours:        
Since the graphs of y = 2^(x−5) and y = 3^(x−5) intersect only at x = 5 and y = 1 it follows that x = 5 is the only solution.

Comment: 7 and 5 are prime numbers. Any integer power of 7 will be a multiple of 7 but not have any other prime factors.  Any integer power of 5 will be a multiple of 5 and not have any other prime factors.  So $7^a = 5^b$ where $a, b$ are non-zero integers is impossible. This is a *really* easy concept.  All numbers can be broken down into primes. But the primes are indivisible each number can only be broken down it one way. So if I say I have a number that breaks down into a bunch of 5s, and if I say is can be broken down into a bunch of 7s, then that is impossible.5s don't break into 7s.

Comment: "Because now I've encountered a similar question where the answer is like yours: Since the graphs of "  That has nothing whatsoever to do with anything I've said.  Those are continuous graphs of *NON* integer powers.

Comment: oh really? I thought that's how you would explain graphically, what you explained is an algebraic way. Isn't it right, only one intersection point ?

Comment: Your graph had only one variable.  If you had to graph $y = 7^x$ and $y = 5^z$ you'd have two graphs in 3-D space.  Each "graph" would be a 2-D surface.  The graphs would intersect at a curve that have an infinite number of points.... *HOWEVER* only *ONE* of those points would exist where both $x$ and $z$ are integers.  And that would be $(0,0)$.  .... to be continued.....

Comment: A simpler we to do this would be to graph $7^x = 5^y$ or $y = \log_5 7^x = x*\log_5 7$.  This will graph to a line with an infinite number of points .  However only *one* of those points will be where both $x$ and $y$ are integers.  That is when $x$ and $y$ are both $0$.  How do know that that is the only point of the graph that has only integers coordinates?  Not by any analytical means.  Pure number theory.  If $7^x = 5^y$ then $x$ and $y$ can't both be non-zero integers because ..... $5$ and $7$ are prime.

Comment: Nice.... thanks for extending your time to write all this. I love this communuity.. @fleablood

Comment: You problem is simple if you realize that if $b \ne c$ then $b^x \ne c^x$ unless $x = 0$.  so if you have $2^{x-5} = 3^{x-5}$ will only have a solution if $x-5 = 0$.  But that has nothing to do with number theory.  Instead we have a problem $7^{a-1} = 5^{b-2}$ but we *DONT* have $a-1 = b-2$. If we are allowe non-integer powers that is $7^{a-1} = 5^{(a-1)\log_5 7} = 5^{b-2}$ so $(a-1)\log_5 7 = b - 2$ which has infinite solutions.  But only *one* pair of integers solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unique factorization means that there is only one way to factorize a positive integer (that means a positive whole number).

In basic terms, what this means is that if you write down a number as a product of primes, there is only one possible way to do that.

For example, if we write $52$ as a product of primes, we have

$52 = 2 \times 2 \times 13$.

There is no other way to write out $52$ as a product of primes.

In your question, you have two expressions on either side of an equals sign, which means that they're the same number. The "answer" which you're talking about is telling you that given that you are writing this number down as a product of its prime factors, the powers of $7$ and powers of $5$ must be the same on both sides of the equation.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, reordering factors is "cheating". The uniqueness referred to means that if you write all of the prime factors down, in order, then *that* is unique. This is often condensed by combining the repeats of a given prime factor into a single power of that prime. In that case, the uniqueness is of (1) the ordered list of distinct prime factors, together with (2) the corresponding list of positive exponents each such factor carries.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers $2,3,5,7$ are all primes.

[Theorem: Any natural number greater than $1$ can be broken in a unique way into a product of primes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

If there are repetitions in this product, this leads to powers ($2\times 2\times 2=2^3$, etc.) and the unicity from the theorem asserts then that these powers are unique, because they determine the number of repetitions for each prime.

For instance, it is impossible to have $2\times n=2\times 2\times m$ if $n$ and $m$ are both odd. That's what "unique" means. The number of factors "$2$" can't be both $1$ and $2$ for the same integer.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $a,b$ are assumed to be *nonnegative* integers, then the claim that "both sides of the equation are [positive] integers" will follow.  So let's begin by assuming that.

In this context *unique factorization* means that (positive) integers can be expressed as a product of (positive) prime integers, with the convention that $1$ is the empty product (one is not considered a prime number in algebra) and that this product is unique except to rearranging the order of the prime numbers (of course $2*3 =3*2$ and similarly).

As a consequence once the prime numbers are collected into like terms, we have unique (positive) *exponents* on the distinct primes that appear in the factorization.

This allows us to obtain equations for $a,b$ by counting the number of times $7$ and $5$ respectively appear on both sides of the equation.

---

Even if we were to open the possible solutions $a,b$ to all integers, not necessarily nonnegative ones, it would not change the final conclusion that $a=1,b=2$.  This can be seen by "clearing fractions" (multiplying both sides of the equation by a positive factor that removes denominators).  Then we would be back to both sides being positive integers and applying the previous reasoning.

Indeed the equation shown could be simplified to:

$$ 5^2 * 7^a = 7 * 5^b $$

by cancelling the factors of $2$ and $3$.

Regardless of whether we *assume* $a,b$ are positive integers, we can invoke unique factorization of *integers* to show $a=1,b=2$.